# Resource level errors when trying to deploy MiniKF on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubeflow

I try to install MiniKF on GCP, following [these steps](https://medium.com/kubeflow/minikf-is-now-available-on-the-gcp-marketplace-ba2d2dc47da3).

I selected the MiniKF virtual-machine solution by Arrikto from the GCP Marketplace.

In the 'Configure & Deploy window' I kept the defaults (same as in the blog post):

[image]

but after I click on the 'Deploy' but, I get the following error:

```
minikf has resource level errors
minikf-2-instance-data-disk: {"ResourceType":"compute.v1.disk","ResourceErrorCode":"QUOTA_EXCEEDED","ResourceErrorMessage":"Quota 'SSD_TOTAL_GB' exceeded. Limit: 500.0 in region europe-west6-a."}
```

[image]

Also when I increase or decrease the disk size or switch the zone, I still keep getting the same error.

Comment: You have a quota problem and maybe a credit problem. Follow this link and review your quota for europe-west6-a for Compute Engine API Persistent Disk Standard. If it is too small request an increase on the same page (Edit Quota). https://console.cloud.google.com/quotas  My quota for us-central1 is 40 TB but zero for europe-west6.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with different zones, but still this quota issue will be there in many of the regions. If you are specific about the configuration and zone, drop a mail to google support team to get your quota extended (if you are using a paid account).
If that is not possible try to install minikf manually on a windows/linux instance on GCP (not from marketplace).